# Entendo uma execução paralela usando fork. Como funciona o fork?

Tags: python, python-3.x, paralelismo

```
import os

def filho():
    print('Ola do filho', os.getpid())
    os._exit(0)

def pai():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()# fornece ID para um novo processo!
        if newpid == 0:
            filho()
        else:
            print('Ola do pai', os.getpid(), newpid)
        if input() == 'q':
            print("Fechando o pai", os.getpid())
            break

pai()
```

Faz sentido `if newpid == 0` ? Não entendi o que o código realmente faz!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note que diferente de *threads*, o `fork()` cria um processo totalmente independente. Para o OS, passam a ser dois executáveis rodando em paralelo, e não dois processos do mesmo executável.

A parte que confunde do `fork()` (e fundamental para entender que ele não é um substituto de *thread*) é que ele duplica o processo **durante a execução**, e **na íntegra**.

Ele **não executa nova instância do início**, ele duplica o processo inclusive no ponto em que se encontra sendo processado, com todos os valores e variáveis intactos.

Justo por isso, acho que o nome "parent" e "child" não são adequados, pois são clones perfeitos.

Em especial, neste trecho:

```
def pai():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()# fornece ID para um novo processo!
        #NESTE MOMENTO TEM 2 CÒDIGOS EM EXECUÇÃO NESTE MESMO PONTO
```

E logo em seguida, cada um dos dois em execução vai cair de um lado do IF:

```
    if newpid == 0 # Zero significa que é a cópia
        filho()
    else:          # Diferente de zero é o original, cujo
                   # newpid é o ID do outro processo (o novo)
```

Como temos o programa duplicado e em execução no mesmo ponto, a única maneira de saber qual é qual é pelo valor diferente retornado em newpid em cada um dos casos.

A melhor maneira de entender o fork é assistir ao filme "THE PRESTIGE", que no Brasil veio como "O GRANDE TRUQUE":

> Trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-zSIAgJszQ

Comment: Se possível, poderia mostrar o mesmo processo acima mas usando Threads para comparar?

Comment: Acabo de editar explicando que thread nao tem nada a ver com fork. Não há o que comparar entre os dois, thread é do mesmo programa, fork é um programa separado. O mesmo, com os mesmos valores, mas totalmente independente.

Comment: Um exemplo: não tem como uma das instâncias do fork acessar diretamente uma variável ou função da outra. São 2 programas separados. Thread é o mesmo programa, só acontece de estar executando determinada função em "paralelo" (na verdade entrelaçando os processos).

Comment: Inclusive, um programa só sabe nativamente que é fork testando o PID mesmo, de resto não teria nem como diferenciar.

Comment: A única coisa "parecida" entre os dois é que 2 instâncias "forkadas" fazem coisas em paralelo, e 2 threads também, mas isso é quase que uma "coincidência". Se um dia alguém relacionar as duas coisas, está mais criando confusão do que entendendo (ou pior, se a pessoa estiver dando uma aula de fork e quiser comparar com thread durante a aula, está atrapalhando o aluno - thread é thread, fork é fork).

Comment: Então o objeto do código que postei é executar as funções filho e pai em paralelo, certo?Por que não chamar filho() logo após newpid?

Comment: Como você sabe que é o filho? Tem 2 programas rodando naquele trecho. Um deles é o original (chamado erradamente de Pai), O outro é o fork (chamado erradamente de filho). Essa é a chave. Entender que lá onde eu pus minha anotação em comment no primeiro trecho, já são 2 programas, não é mais um só.

Comment: vou estudar mais um pouco. Ainda está confuso para mim. Eu pensei que, ao chamar o fork(), já poderia executar a outra função em paralelo!

Comment: Pense no fork assim: se você fosse atingido por um "raio duplicador", como cada um de vocês saberia qual é o original? Os dois seriam a mesma pessoa, só que passam a existir em paralelo..

Comment: Em relação a exemplo, o que eu gostaria é: como criar o mesmo efeito usando Threads ao invés de fork?

Comment: Um thread é um braço novo que nasce no seu corpo. Um fork é você duplicado, adulto, com todas suas memórias e experiência nos 2 corpos.

Comment: Não tem como criar o mesmo efeito. Não tem nada a ver fork com thread

Answer (score 2):

Da [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork):

> **os.fork()**
>
> Fork a child process. Return 0 in the child and the child’s process id in the parent. If an error occurs OSError is raised.

Quando o `os.fork` é chamado, o estado do programa é duplicado em memória. Agora você tem dois processos rodando, e eles precisam saber quem é o processo "pai" e quem é o processo "filho". Pra isso, a função retorna 0 pro processo filho, e outro número pro processo pai.

Vale lembrar que `os.fork` é exclusivo de Unix. Um jeito mais pythonico e multiplataforma de gerenciar processos filho/pai é usar o módulo built-in `multiprocessing` e `if __name__ == '__main__'`, que só será verdadeiro no processo original.

Comment: Se possível, poderia mostrar o mesmo processo acima mas usando Threads para comparar?